# How to handle hibernate exception in quartz job

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, quartz-scheduler

I want to catch a hibernate database exception in my quartz job class, please find my quartz listener and quart job class, I'm trying to test my quartz scheduler with database failure scenario, while executing my quartz job I'm stopping mysql db to verify my quartz job class catching hibernate exception or not.

But the code below does not catch if any db exception occurs.
Can someone help what I'm doing wrong here:

**MyListener.java**

```
@WebListener
public class MyListener extends QuartzInitializerListener {

   private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyListener.class);
   private Scheduler scheduler;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        super.contextInitialized(sce);
        ServletContext ctx = sce.getServletContext();
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) ctx.getAttribute(QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);
        try {
            scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        JobDetail job = newJob(TestQuartzJob.class)
                .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .build();

        CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/20 * * * * ?"))
                .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        scheduler.start();            

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ctx.log("There was an error scheduling the job.", e);
        }
    }
```

**TestQuartzJob.java**

```
public class TestQuartzJob implements Job throws JobExecutionException{

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestQuartzJob.class);
    Session mysession = HibernateUtilities.getJobsSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = mysession.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) {

        try {

            Student getstudName = (Student) mysession.
                    createCriteria(Student).add(eq(“student_id", “stud1234")).uniqueResult();

            String name = getstudName.getName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("--- Error in job!");
            JobExecutionException e2 = new JobExecutionException(e);
            // this job will refire immediately
            e2.refireImmediately();
            throw e2;
        }

    }

}
```